# Combinations of groups in a VisualStateManager

Tags: wpf

I'm currently working on a style for ComboBox controls. The popup part has all the items that are available for selection. The preselected item has a background colour, all others are just white. With the default style, when any item from that popup is hovered, it gets the same background colour as the selected item, and the selected item loses its special highlighting. I can't get this to work with the VisualStateManager.

There's two groups: CommonStates and SelectionStates. CommonStates contains the state name MouseOver, which applies when an item is hovered. SelectionStates contains the state name Selected, which applies to the one selected item.

I've set the background colour for these two states. Now the following happens: When the popup is opened, only the selected item is highlighted. When I hover any item, this item is highlighted as well. The selected item only loses its highlighting permanently, after it has been hovered once.

I'd like the selected item to lose its colour permanently and immediately when another item is hovered, like with the default platform style.

How can this be done? Do I need to use triggers instead of the VisualStateManager here?

Here's some XAML code, based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.100%29.aspx:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).Color">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#9bceff" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).Color">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#9bceff" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).Color">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#dddddd" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware all groups "live" in parallel. That means one state of each group is active. The drawback is if you modify the same element from different groups the last setting wins. In your case you modify the target "Border" from both groups. The only solution is to add another control, modify on in the SelectionState, the other in the CommonStates.

Comment: I just wanted to add this to my question: Can I specify combinations of states from different groups? Say, MouseOver AND Selected, then do something else? Like with a MultiTrigger for example.

Comment: Unfortunately VisualStates do not offer combinations.

Comment: In general I like the VisualStates. But sometimes some creativity is needed. Usually showing/hiding controls that overlay. Right now I now good idea for your special case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light">
                            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>                         
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#9bceff"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>         
    </Style>
```